# Test report with XCPretty using terminal is not show pass cases in passing tab(section)

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode-ui-testing, xcode8.2

I have generate test report by using XCPretty. In  this HTML report there are basically three sections.In first section all test cases are show ,in second section show failed cases but in third section it does not show  passing case.

can you help me find out the solution?

Comment: it works for me in the 0.2.6 version. What version do you have?

Comment: Dear sir, Can u tell me procedure of generating report of XCUITest using XCPretty with terminal

Comment: "|xcpretty --report html --output ../TestReport/report.html" - Append this to your script to generate html report.